# force an update of information on a $watch variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js

So I've been trying to work with [angularjs-nvd3-directives](https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives) and for the most part it's been great. I've come to my actual use-case though, and it doesn't work as expected. What I'm doing is making a chart editor, so you would change settings in real-time about the chart and see those changes live. [Here's an example of changing the x axis in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ORCLW?p=preview). Now, you might notice that the data changes repeatedly. I want to change all of these properties without changing the data, but if you comment out the lines that randomize the data, it doesn't work as expected.

I did some digging in the source code, and I found [this curious line](https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives/blob/master/src/directives/nvd3Directives.js#L158) that seems to me like it only watches the data variable. Is there a way I can force angular to update, even if the data doesn't change? Setting it to itself doesn't seem to work.

Also, in the example it updates every 1500 ms because of a `setInterval`. Is there a better way to do that? I feel like making it work off of a `change` event would be better, but I don't know where to start with that.

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest

Comment: The docs even say I should be using $scope.$apply() (which the example is doing), if it's in a controller. I'm not sure how this would help, unless you have an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I had to go with was to set an unused property on the object, and increment it any time I needed it to change.

Answer (score 0):

> setting it to itself doesn't seem to work.

That didn't work because angular does a `===` equality check. 
Simply solution:

`data = angular.copy(data)`

This will make `data` distinct from previous value of `data` but still functionally equivalent.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something? http://plnkr.co/edit/rhrbIe3jdH4Cbdka0sF0?p=preview